# Django 1.9.4 Filter many-to-one on 3 models with condition

Tags: django

I am trying to filter fields from three tables.
I need join 1 table as list and 2 table with condition.
I have Django 1.9.4, MySql 5.6.17

This is my models.py:

```
class Products(models.Model):
    fullname    = models.CharField(max_length=250, db_index=True)
    code        = models.CharField(max_length=15, db_index=True, null=True)
    authors     = models.CharField(max_length=300, db_index=True, null=True)
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.fullname

class Barcodes(models.Model):
    product     = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    barcode     = models.CharField(max_length=25, db_index=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.barcode

class Prices(models.Model):
    product     = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price       = models.FloatField(default=0)
    shop_id     = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    shop_name   = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.shop_name
```

I need get all Products, joined group_concat(distinct barcode) and joined price with shop_id = 1, if string in Prices not exist - return price = 0

I did so:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Products.objects.values('id', 'fullname', 'authors', 'code', 'theme').annotate(barcodes=Concat('barcodes__barcode'))
```

And use aggregate function:

```
class Concat(Aggregate):
    function = 'GROUP_CONCAT'
    template = '%(function)s(%(distinct)s%(expressions)s)'
    def __init__(self, expression, distinct=False, **extra):
        super(Concat, self).__init__(
            expression,
            distinct='DISTINCT ' if distinct else '',
            output_field=models.CharField(),
            **extra)
```

How do I add Prices with shop_id = 1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Q

...

def get_queryset(self):
    return Products.objects.filter(Q(prices__shop_id=1) | Q(prices__shop_id__isnull=True)).values('id', 'fullname', 'authors', 'code', 'tema', 'prices__price').annotate(barcodes=Concat('barcodes__barcode', True))
```